# Firebase Cloud Messaging Java client

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, libgdx, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to have push message functionality for a libgdx game so I was thinking about using Google Firebase Cloud Messaging Api. Problem is I don't know any iOS so I want Java client on iOS end. Is there such a client? Or is there some better alternative than using FCM if I just want to be able to send messages from a server to libgdx cross-platform Java game?

I don't need to be able to receive messages when game isn't active, i.e. in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FCM is the way to go on Android, on iOS you should use Apple's service (APNs) directly. The advantage is that you need no third party software in your iOS project and you can work with the bindings provided by RoboVM.

You can find my code for using FCM on Android and APNs on iOS within your libgdx game with some further documentation on [Github](https://github.com/MrStahlfelge/gdx-pushmessages).

Comment: Great! I will have a look!

Comment: But on server side do I need to implement two solutions then? Both FCM and apple's solution?

Comment: Yes. If your server is Java-based, I recommend you to integrate [pushy](https://github.com/jchambers/pushy) for APNs. FCM has an own lib to use, so it is a simple switch statement.

Comment: Ok. Can I also use websockets with Java. Might that be simpler?

Comment: I don't understand what websockets have to do with push notifications.

Comment: I was more thinking about how to solve my problem but I guess that isn't the answer to my own question.